# is the memory stick pro duo the same as micro sd adapter?

Tags: psp

Is the memory stick pro duo, used for the PSP2000, the same as a micro sd card adapter? Will either an sd card or a micro sd card adapter fit and work in the memory stick pro duo slot?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is nowhere near the website's topic.

Comment: @BlaXpirit It's about peripherals for a gaming device isn't it?

Comment: Game specific hardware, which a PSP is, is on topic of this site.

Comment: On-topic, yes.  Effort shown: Zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Micro SD and Memory Stick Pro Duo are two completely different types of memory cards.